# How to search for neuters ending in -tus?

Tags: vocabulary, resource-request, dictionary, neuter

For reasons of rhyming I sometimes need to search for Latin words with specific kinds of endings.
Translating songs to Latin is a hobby that seems to inevitably lead to this need.

I would like to search for third declension neuters ending in *-tus* (genitive *-toris*), like *litus* and *pectus*.
Is there a tool that allows me to do that?
Sufficient information — nouns listed with their gender and nominative form — exists in online databases, but I do not know how to make the search.
I know I can [search for words ending in *-tus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=tus&lang=la), but the amount of results is enormous and I would like to filter out the masculines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extracted the dictionary file from [Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html) (which admittedly has its flaws) while working on my (beta) [Latin-English Dictionary](http://www.latin-english.com/).

Though I still haven't developed many advanced search tools, I now have the luxury of running any SQL query I have a mind to. The following query returns 6 results:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE part_of_speech = 'N' AND stem1 LIKE '%tus' AND gender = 'N'
```

- latus
- littus (variant)
- litus
- pectus
- tus
- vetus (but only used in plural: *vetera* "old times")

Comment: Thanks! Can I run that SQL query somewhere in the web UI or is it something only you can do at this point?

Comment: No, it's not exposed unfortunately, so it's not really an answer to your question of "how" to do this--just an answer to the specific question.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. You answered my specific question and gave hope for answering the general question in the future, so I will accept this answer. Please let me know when such searches become possible!